Movie with a vegetarian Hot Dog Stand?
I was wondering if anyone knows about a movie that has a scene with a guy selling vegetarian hot dogs at a stand?
(This is the worst info, apologies!)
I've seen a part of a movie ages ago where there was this specific scene and it keeps on coming back to my mind.
The movie is set in the US, I can't really remember the time, it could have been anything from the 90s onwards. I don't remember any other plot details unfortunately! I saw it maybe a year ago - but it was on Television so it could potentially be an old movie!
Any input is greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Are you looking for The Happy Poet?
Here's the trailer: 



And the synopsis:
Bill, an out-of-work poet, puts his heart, soul, and last few dollars into starting an all-organic mostly-vegetarian food stand. Complications with the business jeopardize his dreams for a hot dog-free future.
